# Alternative to using ref in foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach, ref

I have a modifying method with a signature like

```
private bool Modify(ref MyClass obj);
```

that will make modifications to `obj` and indicate succes with it's return value. `Modify` is not reassigning the reference (I know that this wouldn't work), just modifying instance fields, so I want to use it to do something like the following:

```
foreach(MyClass obj in myList)
{
    bool success = Modify(obj);
    // do things depending on success
}
```

I am running into a problem compiling as `obj` is "not being passed with the `ref` keyword". However, if I put the ref keyword in like so:

```
bool success = Modify(ref obj);
```

I get "cannot use `obj` as a `ref`/`out` because it is a 'foreach iteration variable". I understand that foreach uses an immutable iterator and that's why this doesn't work.

My question is what is the easiest alternative to make something like this work?

I have tried using

```
foreach(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    bool success = Modify(ref myList[i]);
    // do things depending on success
}
```

but they I get "a property or indexer may not be passed as an out of ref parameter".

Thanks your help.

Comment: maybe use simple`for` loop instead of `foreach`

Comment: That's not possible with `foreach` I guess. Because `myList` can be a generator, read-only list, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to pass object by ref to this Modify function?

Comment: @James so that I can modify it. Right?

Comment: You can modify the properties of `obj` without using `ref`. Using `ref` allows you to modify the reference itself. This is almost certainly not what you are intending.

Comment: Define how you modify it. If you are updating properties or fields, you do not need a `ref` parameter. If you are completely reassigning the reference, that's a separate issue.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for clarifying. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Please update your question to include how you use `obj` inside `Modify`

Comment: First - the outter class shouldn't modify the inner class, it should be done over calling methods of inner class or by using command pattern.

Comment: @RufusL, passing by reference has a very specific meaning and it's a mistake to suggest classes are passed by reference by default. A class' *reference* is *passed by value*.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, true, I've removed that comment. thank you!

Comment: Same, i hate this about c#. You can see the same question asked over and over with the only answer that "you shouldnt do that"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You state

> Modify is not reassigning the reference

Therefore, there is no reason the `Modify(ref MyClass)` function needs to pass argument by `ref`.

You should be able to do the same "modifications", whatever that is (please clarify that) by passing the object reference by value, i.e. removing the `ref` keyword.

So, the fix here should be changing your Modify function signature from `Modify(ref MyClass)` to `Modify(MyClass)`

Comment: The modifications are complicated and I would argue not relevant to the example.

Answer (score 22):

Any type within C# is passed actually *by value*. When you pass an instance of a class to a method what is *actually* passed is not the instance itself but a *reference* to it which itself is passed *by value*. So *effectivly* you're passing instances of a class as reference - which is why you call them reference-types.

In your case you just *modify* an existing instance referenced by that reference-value in your method, no need to use the `ref`-keyword.

```
foreach(var m in myList)
{
    MyMethod(m);
}

MyMethod(MyClass instance)
{
    instance.MyProperty = ...
}
```

If you'd really pass the reference *by reference* you'd re-assign the `obj` on every iteration within your loop which isn't allowed within a `foreach`-block. This would be similar to the following:

```
foreach(var m in myList)
{
    m = new MyClass();
}
```

On the other side you could also use a classic for-loop. However you'd need a temporary variable to store the outcome of your method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
    var tmp = myList[i];
    MyMethod(ref tmp);
    myList[i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This truly answers the conceptual question being asked, whether or not it is the right solution for the OP

Answer (score 1):

use a temp variable to bypass the message

```
foreach(MyClass obj in myList)
{
    MyClass objTemp = obj;
    bool success = Modify(ref objTemp);
    // do things depending on success
}

private MyMethod(ref MyClass instance)
{
    instance.MyProperty = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your array to a Span:

```
int[] nums = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int i = 0;
foreach (ref var item in nums.AsSpan())
{
    item += 10;
    Console.WriteLine(nums[i++]);
}
```

> output:
> 11
> 12
> 13
> 14
> 15

You can modify the iteration variable because Span Enumerator's Current property is of ref T type.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using LINQ.

**My Code:**

```
    private static List<string> _test = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Test { get => _test; set => _test = value; }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string numString = "abcd";

        _test.Add("ABcd");
        _test.Add("bsgd");

        string result = _test.Where(a => a.ToUpper().Equals(numString.ToUpper()) == true).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(result + " linq");
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question on modifying a list within a loop?

Comment: I suggested a way to solve it without having to use for or foreach statement.

Comment: The questioner seemed to be looking for an easier way than for ref in for or foreach.