# Foreach loop passing the iteration variable to a method with and without ref - dont get why it wont allow it with ref

Tags: c#, foreach

This morning I've struggled to understand the following and I am hoping someone has a good explanation of why this wont work. I made an example on `LinqPad` that replicates my issue:

```
void Main()
{
  var myPeople = new People();
  myPeople.MyPeople.Add(new Person { Name = "Joe", Surname = "Doe" });

  foreach (var person in myPeople.MyPeople)
  {
      //this is intermediate variable is still a reference to the iteration variable
       var intermediate = person;
       myPeople.ChangeName(ref intermediate);

      //both names were changed, so why cant i just pass in 'person' directly since its still changing it.

      intermediate.Name.Dump();
      person.Name.Dump();
  }

}

 public class People
 {
     public People()
     {
        MyPeople = new List<Person>();
     }

    public List<Person> MyPeople { get; set; }

    public void ChangeName(ref Person person)
    {
       person.Name = "Changed";
    }
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

So [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838079/why-cant-we-assign-a-foreach-iteration-variable-whereas-we-can-completely-modi) explains the `foreach` variable is a read only variable that is why you can't replace it with another- makes sense, but if i pass it into the method above `ChangeName` with a `ref`, compiler wont allow it [CS1657](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1657). But if i remove the `ref` on the `ChangeName` method it will allow me to pass in the foreach variable, but technically its still a `reference` without explicitly saying its a `ref` right?

So why is this happening? Furthermore if I assign it to an intermediate variable above, then it will allow me to pass it in as a `ref` even though its still a reference to the original, so technically pointing to the same memory location, meaning same object right?

So my question really is why the C# compiler wont let me pass in iteration variable to a method with a `ref`

Further clarity on question by Rafalon: 
Why does the compiler not allow myPeople.ChangeName(ref person) but allows myPeople.ChangeName(ref intermediate) when the `person` variable points to the same object as the `intermediate` variable?

Comment: `public void ChangeName(Person person) {...}` - you can drop `ref` here

Comment: yes that will allow it, but that is not the question @DmitryBychenko

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes i set it to expect a `ref` to illustrate my question...

Comment: "but technically its still a reference" - the difference here is "a reference" vs "a reference to a reference"; but just to add confusion, c# "latest" supports `ref foreach`, where the l-value **is a reference** (i.e. a `ref Person` in this case), in which case it *would* work! Note: most people will never need to know or care about `ref foreach` :)

Comment: Suppose we put `public void ChangeName(ref Person person) {person = null;}`. What is the desired `forloop` behaviour? In case of `intermediate`, it's `intermediate == null` while loop variable (`person`) is not changed.

Comment: So the question is "*Why does the compiler not allow `myPeople.ChangeName(ref person)` but allows `myPeople.ChangeName(ref intermediate)` when `person = intermediate`?*", right?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko your comment is completely wrong and further illustrates my question, both will become `null`

Comment: Just to be explicit: you don't need `ref` here - I think you know that, but I just wanted to call it out

Comment: @MarcGravell yes i know:p

Comment: @Rafalon correct

Comment: `//this is intermediate variable is still a reference to the iteration variable` No it isn't. It is a reference to the same object that `iteration` references. That distinction may seem subtle, but it is important.

Comment: @mjwills hmm, need to think about this

Comment: Before we discuss further, please clarify whether you understand why https://dotnetfiddle.net/WNJxQU doesn't compile. _Note that if you understand that, it becomes reasonably clear why it can't be a `ref` parameter, which is why it is important to use this as a starting point._

Comment: And please re-read MSDN about ref- and out-keywords.

Comment: @mjwills As to your edit, I think the reason for OP's confusion is precisely that `var intermediate = person;` means "*the `person` variable points to the same object as the `intermediate` variable*" and **not** *the `person` variable **is the same** as the `intermediate` variable*"

Comment: Agreed @Rafalon. My earlier comment (and everyone else's) thankfully helped the OP come / move to that realisation. The edit was just to make the question more useful for future readers.

Comment: thanks for all the insight guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, [the notes on CS1657](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1657) explains all of this; the l-value of a regular `foreach` is considered "readonly" - you can't do:

```cs
person = new Person();
```

for example. The `ref` usage requires the parameter **not** be read-only, otherwise we have violated the promise of read-only-less, because the method could modify something that is meant to be read-only. In this case, since `Person` is a class, this only relates to the actual reference itself, not the underlying object.

There is good news, though: we now have `in`, which is like `ref`, but for read-only scenarios, so: change `public void ChangeName(ref Person person)` to `public void ChangeName(in Person person)` and it should work:

```cs
myPeople.ChangeName(in person);
```

The restriction on this is that you then, in your `ChangeName` method, can't do things like:

```cs
public void ChangeName(in Person person)
{
    person = new Person(); // invalid
}
```

Emphasis: this `in` usage isn't really intended for classes; it is intended for `struct`, and in particular `readonly struct` - to avoid defensive stack copies of complex and large value-types.

In latest versions of C#, there is also a `ref readonly` concept, by-which the l-value **is a ref `Foo`** (for whatever type `Foo`). This requires a custom iterator with a `public ref Foo Current {get;}` accessor instead of a `public Foo Current {get;}` accessor, i.e. it is explicitly tied into ref-return. When the l-value **is a ref**, you can use it in a method that takes a `ref`.

---

Important emphasis, although I realize OP knows this: you don't need `ref` in this scenario since `Person` is a class itself; the code would work just fine without the `ref`, and the object would be updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass ref intermediate, you pass a reference to the variable intermediate, not to the object pointed by it. If you assign a new Person to the person variable inside ChangeName, intermediate would get changed.

That’s why you are not allowed to pass ref person in the foreach, because you would be able to change the value of the foreach variable.

Comment: I didn’t get what you mean by “both will change”, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: u pass a reference to both implictly, by changing intermediate, you change the property on the intermediate variable and iteration variable

Comment: Exactly, you are able to change the properties of the object pointed by “person”, but not which object  “person” is pointing to.

Comment: Did you look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/WNJxQU yet @JohnChris? You understand why it doesn't compile?

Comment: @mjwills yeah i did, because you are trying to replace the iteration variable with null, not a property on it. That is answered by a post a linked in my question above. My question, ill admit not worded well, you can pass the iterator to a method to get properties changed on it where it's implicitly referenced but if i expliclty set `ref` it wont allow it. My goal was never to replace the object but alter its properties.

Comment: `My goal was never to replace the object but alter its properties.` Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380539/alternative-to-using-ref-in-foreach @JohnChris. **You do not need `ref` to do that.** Just as Dmitry said earlier.

Comment: @mjwills i know i dont need `ref` or `in` , was just trying to understand the c# compiler logic, which Marc answered...